# Check the type of an argument without using COND, IF, WHEN, UNLESS, or CASE

Tags: common-lisp

I have this function that is working fine when the inputs are number: it returns `T` if both inputs have the same sign, `NIL` otherwise. However, when I give for example two `'a`, I get this error:

> a is not a real number

I'm finding it tricky to filer non numbers without using `COND`, `IF`, `WHEN`, `UNLESS`, or `CASE`. Here is the function definition I have so far.

```
(defun same-sign (x y)
  (or (and (>= x 0) (>= y 0))
      (and (< x 0) (< y 0))))
```

Comment: What *should* happen when given non-numbers, apart from an error?

Comment: if 'a is entered then nil returns. If x, a variable is entered I get an error. Not sure how to handle it. However, is not a test case. Not sure how i would handle it. I posted an answer check it out. @coredump

Comment: Why not `(defun same-sign (x y) (= (signum x) (signum y)))`?  http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_signum.htm#signum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun same-sign (x y)
    (and (typep x 'real) (typep y 'real)
    (or (and (>= x 0) (>= y 0))
        (and (< x 0) (< y 0)))))
```

Comment: Please use indentation. http://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21301536)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `check-type`:

```
(defun same-sign (x y)
  (check-type real x)
  (check-type real y)
  (= (signum x) (signum y)))
```

Since [signum](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_signum.htm#signum) can also work with complex numbers, you could use `number` instead of `real` here, if it makes sense for your application.

`Signum` treats `0` separately, though, so you might use `minusp` instead (wrapping to potentially un-generalize the boolean):

```
(defun binary-sign (n)
  "Returns -1 if n is negative, 1 otherwise."
  (check-type real n)
  (if (minusp n) -1 1))

(defun same-sign-p (x y)
  "Returns whether both given real numbers are either both negative or both
non-negative."
  (= (binary-sign x) (binary-sign y)))
```

As you see, you can avoid writing two checks by putting the check into the more detailed function.  However, you can imagine that `minusp` already has such a check, so you can be reasonably sure that an appropriate type-error will be signalled anyway if you don't call this with reals.

Answer (score 1):

You might mean type `real` and not `number`. Type `number` consists of `real` (integers and floats) and `complex` (2 real components) values. An example of a complex number is `#C(1 2) = 1 + 2i`

Try `(and (realp x) ...)` to filter `real` numbers, equivalent to `(and (typep x 'real) ...)`.

Also `(typecase x (real ..))` or using a generic function and `(defmethod foo ((x real)) ..)` work, except you seem to want to restrict yourself to basic logical operators.

Comment: In that case, `nil` could mean either "inputs are reals with unequal signs" or "inputs are not all reals". If you only care about the T result, then fine. But in the general case, the calling code always needs to decode what `nil` means, by checking for example if both inputs are real (again). And then, this is not a great design in my opinion. Better have the function fail with an error (or a secondary value) if the functions cannot return a sensible output for some inputs.

Comment: Answered it. @zut check it out.